# problem while doing gzip over ssh

Tags: unix, ssh

I am getting below error while running gzip command over ssh
ssh 123@HPUX "gzip"
ksh: gzip:  not found

whereas if i am running tar in same way it is working properly.
ssh  123@HPUX "tar"
tar: usage  tar [-]{txruc}[eONvVwAfblhm{op}][0-7[lmh]] [tapefile] [blocksize] [[-C directory] file] ...

Can you please suggest why am i getting this error and how can i overcome this problem ?

When i tried following step gzip is working properly
ssh 123@HPUX
gzip
gzip: compressed data not written to a terminal. Use -f to force compression.
For help, type: gzip -h
which means that gzip is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$path` may be set differently for an interactive login session, versus 
executing a single command via ssh.  Does it work if you specify an absolute path to gzip?
Try logging in interactively, and use the command `which gzip` to show where the
binary is.  Perhaps it's something like /usr/local/gnu/gzip .  (You might want to do
`echo $path` too, and make a note of it for comparison purposes.) Then try using
that path in your batch SSH command, i.e. `ssh 123@HPUX "/usr/local/gnu/gzip"` to see
what happens.  The command `ssh 123@HPUX 'echo $path'`  (note single quotes!) should tell you how your `$path` is set in that context -- if you compare that to your interactive `$path`, you'll probably see a difference that explains why gzip isn't found in the first version of your batch command.

Comment: I am not even trying to do any compress. I only executed gzip with no arguments. In an ideal case it should give me output of how to run gzip.

Comment: @user: I understood that...I expanded my answer a bit to clarify what I think you should try.

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess: it's `ksh` raising the error the first time. When you do a full ssh login, are you using `ksh`? Are you running any scripts that modify its path?

Comment: No i ran the ssh from command line. and after full ssh login my default shell is ksh